# Tkinter StringVar() not updating label's background color

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been working on a project recently, and in it, I have to dynamically change the background color of the variable. I am doing it by using Tkinter String Var(), and it is not showing any error, yet its not working either.  This code below is not the actual project, but also has the same problem of not updating the background color.

```
from tkinter import *
w = Tk()
gridcolor = [[StringVar() for i in range (4)]for j in range (4) ]

for k in range(4):
    for l in range(4):
        gridcolor[k][l].set("white")
        print(gridcolor[k][l].get())
labels = [[Label(w,text ="Hi",bg = gridcolor[i][j].get()).grid(row=i, column=j)for i in range(0,4)]for j in range(0,4)]
def colorchange():
global gridcolor
for k in range(4):
    for l in range(4):
        gridcolor[k][l].set("red")
colorchange()
w.mainloop()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tkinter Vars only work with specific widget options, that always have `variable` in their names (`textvariable=`, for example).  The background color is not one of these options.  But you don't really need it to be - rather than saving a list of StringVars, save a list of Labels (you're doing this anyway), and call `.config(bg="red")` on each of those.

Comment: Also note that the `grid()` method always returns `None`, so that is what all the values will be in the `labels` list you're creating.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `StringVar` class in this way. The vast majority of widget attributes are static and won't update if you use a `StringVar` for a value.

If you want to change the color of something by changing an instance of `StringVar`, you'll have to use the `trace` method of the variable to call a function that updates your widgets whenever the value changes.